# How to use secret keys from secrets.yml in Travis ci?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

I need two keys from S3 storage in my repo to make Travis tests pass.

I used travis gem to encrypt my keys:

```
travis encrypt "aws_access_key=MYSUPERSECRETKEY" --add env
travis encrypt "aws_secret_key=MYSUPERSECRETKEY" --add env
```

And got travis.yml strings:

```
env:
  secure: SOMESTUFFuru4irlVd3Hd6c+x2joz6g=
  secure: SOMESTUFFuru4gfgfgfgfgfggfgfgfHd6c+x2joz6g=
```

Than I added these keys to carrierwave.rb:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: "AWS",
    aws_access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_key,
    region: Rails.application.secrets.aws_region
  }
  config.fog_directory = "busketS3"
end
```

And pushed it on Github. But I got an error:

```
Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)
```

My secrets.yml:

```
development:
  facebook_key: "***********"
  facebook_secret: "***************"
  google_key: "***********************"
  google_secret: "***********************"
  aws_access_key: "***********************"
  aws_secret_key: "***********************"
  aws_region: "***********************"
test:
  secret_key_base: "***********************"
  aws_access_key: "***********************"
  aws_secret_key: "***********************"
  aws_region: "***********************"
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Where is your `secrets.yml` can you show us(without keys :))?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: errors related to your production `env`? When errors raises?

Comment: RAILS_ENV=test `/home/travis/build/Soll/flashcards/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.32.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in 'validate_options': Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)`

Answer (score 2):

I think a problem in your `secrets.yml`:

```
secret_key_base: "***********************"
aws_access_key: "***********************"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
aws_secret_key: "***********************"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
aws_region: "***********************"
```

But keys should be, according error that you have:

> Missing required arguments: `aws_access_key_id`, `aws_secret_access_key`
>   (ArgumentError)

not:

```
aws_access_key, aws_secret_access
```

Comment: do you fix the `carrierwave.rb` too?

Comment: Yes. Now it looks like `CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: "AWS",
    aws_access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key,
    region: Rails.application.secrets.aws_region
  }
  config.fog_directory = "*******"
end`